# Java: How to turn a text file with string in format {i,j},{i,j},{i,j} into a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: java

My text file is as follows :
{11-11,22},{33-33,44},...{88-88,99}

How can I turn this into a 2 dimensional array in Java in the form:
[[11-11,22],[33-33,44],...[88-88,99]]

Comment: Um, what exactly is `[[11-11,22],[33-33,44],...[88-88,99]]` suppose to represent? What is `11-11`? A string?

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve this objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

```
    String source = "{11-11,22},{33-33,44},{88-88,99}";
    String[] splittedSource = source.split("(?<=\\}),(?=\\{)");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([^,]+),([^\\}]+)");
    String[][] result = new String[splittedSource.length][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < splittedSource.length; i++) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(splittedSource[i]);
        while(m.find()) {
            result[i][0] = m.group(1);
            result[i][1] = m.group(2);
            System.out.print(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2) + "\n");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
```

### Explanation:

`source.split("(?<=\\}),(?=\\{)");` - splitting source on '`,`' character preceded by '`}`' and followed by '`{`'

`Pattern.compile("\\{([^,]+),([^\\}]+)");` - two **capturing groups** in parenthesis "`()`", first contains all characters other than '`,`' until it reaches '`,`', second contains all characters after the '`,`' except '`}`'

`new String[splittedSource.length][2];` - it's `[3][2]` in this example

`Matcher m = p.matcher(splittedSource[i]);` - here you say that you will check given pattern against each element from `splittedSource[]`

Output you get from this code:

```
11-11 22
33-33 44
88-88 99
[[11-11, 22], [33-33, 44], [88-88, 99]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().
    getResourceAsStream("input/test.txt"));
    String line = in.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split("},");
    String[][] finalArray = new String[tokens.length][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        tokens[i] = tokens[i].replace("{", "");
        tokens[i] = tokens[i].replace("}", "");
        finalArray[i] = tokens[i].split(",");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(finalArray[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: ----
text.txt : {11-11,22},{33-33,44},{88-88,99}

Output :
[11-11, 22]
[33-33, 44]
[88-88, 99]